# Chain doing noises... what to do?

Tags: maintenance, chain, mechanical

I have a city bike with a 3 gear hub on the back.

From some time now, from time to time I hear (I think) the chain clicking/cracking (noise) specially when going up a ramp.

Initially I though it was just missing oil, but after greasing the chain it still does the same noise.

Any tips to solve that?

Extra info: When I hear the noise it seems like the chain jumps in the cog?!?! I am not sure though.

Comment: Politely ask the chain to be silent :-) I thing it is difficult to say what causes it without seeing it. You could go to your LBS, they are able to check it.

Comment: @w4rumy I would :) but this thing is annoying specially  when going up hill. This chain jumping makes it harder.

Comment: How confident do you feel about being able to sort this yourself? For example, buying a new chain and fitting it is simple enough, but from what you're saying its by no means certain that its (just) the chain that's the problem. I think if you're unsure it might be worth your while to take the bike to your LBS as @w4rumy suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your gears need adjusting. How to do so would depend on the type of the gears you have exactly.

But if you're getting the clicking and jumping gears, then your gears are out of index.

Comment: It could also be a worn chain and/or sprocket. Also, it sounds like he probably has in internal gear hub. If that's the case, I'm not sure that the gears being out of alignment would cause the chain to jump.

Comment: @THEMike        +1 for the adjustment+index